# how to join tables and 2 select together

Tags: mysql

I have the following two queries, how can I join them together?

Query1:

```
SELECT product_name, count(product_name) as count_product_name
FROM ps_order_detail
WHERE id_shop = 1
group by product_name
order by count_product_name DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Query2:

```
SELECT count(*) as count, concat(decade, '-', decade + 9) as year
FROM (SELECT floor(year(`birthday`) / 10) * 10 as decade
      FROM ps_customer) C
GROUP BY decade;
```

the first query is to get the top 5 product name that ordered the most.

the second query is get the customer birthday year and group them by every ten years.

I want to know the age group that order the top 5 product.

result should be

```
product name, years, count
productA 1990-2009  100
ProductA 2000-2019  20
ProductB 1980-1999  20
ProductB 1990-2009  25
ProductB 2000-2019  20
```

...

I do have a third table to have the connection.

```
create table ps_orders(
  id_customer,
id_order
);

create table ps_customer(
id_customer, birthday
);
create table ps_order_detail(
id_order, product_name
);
```

I am not sure how to put them all together, I can input the product name one by one to get the years.

```
SELECT count(*) as count, concat(decade, '-', decade + 9) as year 
FROM (SELECT floor(year(birthday) / 10) * 10 as decade 
      FROM ps_customer as CU, 
           ps_orders as O, 
           ps_order_detail as OD 
      WHERE CU.id_customer = O.id_customer 
        AND O.id_order = OD.id_order 
        AND OD.product_name = 'product Name A' 
    ) C    
GROUP BY decade;
```

Comment: Have you ever worked with SQL joins before ?

Comment: yes, but I am not sure how to put them all together, I can input the product name one by one to get the years. SELECT count(*) as count, concat(decade, '-', decade + 9) as year
FROM (SELECT floor(year(`birthday`) / 10) * 10 as decade
      FROM ps_customer as CU, ps_orders as O, ps_order_detail as OD
WHERE CU.id_customer = O.id_customer
AND O.id_order = OD.id_order
AND OD.product_name = 'product Name A'

) C
GROUP BY decade;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your second query, but instead of specifying a particular product, put that into the grouping. Then join that with the subquery that returns the top 5 products to limit it.

```
SELECT product_name, concat(decade, '-', decade + 9) AS year, count(*) AS count
FROM (SELECT p.product_name, floor(year(birthday) / 10) * 10 as decade
      FROM (SELECT product_name, count(*) as count_product_name
            FROM ps_order_detail
            WHERE id_shop = 1
            group by product_name
            order by count_product_name DESC
            LIMIT 5) AS p
      JOIN ps_order_detail AS od ON od.product_name = p.product_name
      JOIN ps_orders AS o on o.id_order = od.id_order
      JOIN ps_customer AS c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
      WHERE od.id_shop = 1) AS x
GROUP BY product_name, decade
```

Comment: this only return 5 rows, but I want 5 products and each products should have more than 1 row for the group year.

Comment: Your sample result only has 5 rows with 2 products.

Comment: Updated the query to join with the subquery that returns the top 5 products.

Comment: ok good, I think this should work. just need to edit the is_order to id_order. thanks